# Segmentation fault after pthread_cancel

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

In my program I have two threads, one calculates some recursive function and other displays "progress dots" as first threads does calculations. There is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define test_errno(msg) do{if (errno) {perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}} while(0)

void *progressDotsThread(void* _arg){
    for(int i=0;;i++){
    printf(".");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    }
}
void *seriesCalculateThread(void* n){
    int result;

    if((long)n==1) return (void*)(1);
    else if((long)n==2) return (void*)(-5);
    else{
         int nmin1 = (long)seriesCalculateThread( (void*) ( (long)n -1   ));
         int nmin2 = (long)seriesCalculateThread( (void*) ( (long)n -2   ));
         result = nmin1*((long)n)*nmin2;
         return (void*)(result);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    long n=0;
    int result =0;
    pthread_t w1,w2;

    printf("Give n\n");
    scanf ("%d",&n);

    if(n<1){
        printf("Value must be higher than 0");
    }
    else{

        errno= pthread_create(&w2,NULL,seriesCalculateThread,(void *)n);
        test_errno("pthread_create");
        errno= pthread_create(&w1,NULL,progressDotsThread,NULL);
        test_errno("pthread_create");

        if(!pthread_join(w2,(void**)&result)){
            errno = pthread_cancel(w1); //<--- Where segmentation fault happens
            test_errno("pthread_cancel");
        }
        printf("%d\n", result);

    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I `pthread_create` both of them and then I `if(!pthread_join)` the one that does calculations and when calculations finish I cancel the one that display dots.

```
if(!pthread_join(w2,(void**)&result)){
                errno = pthread_cancel(w1); //<--- Where segmentation fault happens
                test_errno("pthread_cancel");
            }
```

I do that although I get segmentation fault after pthread_cancel(w1) is called and I have no idea why that happens.

I tried compiling it terminal with `gcc -g -Wall -pthread psthreadss.c -lpthread` and it didn't work as well as in eclipse. I use Ubuntu 18.04 if that's revelant.

Comment: Code such as `errno= pthread_create(...)` will destroy the value of `errno`.  `errno` is not the same as the return value from a function call.  The return value tells you *if* the function worked.  `errno` tells you *why* it failed, and if the function call didn't fail the value of `errno` is irrelevant.

Comment: You are telling me this regarding to pthread_cancel? Also when I removed all errno's from my code it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and then I `if(!pthread_join)` the one that does calculations and when calculations finish I cancel the one that display dots.

Your program has a logical bug, and a memory corruption bug.

The logical bug: you are assuming that `!pthread_join` means that calculations finished. It *doesn't* mean that. `pthread_join` returns non-zero status *only* if you invoked it with incorrect parameters (thread id `w2` is not known, has not been started, or has already been joined).

Your code should instead look something like this:

```
int rc = pthread_join(w2, ...);
assert(rc == 0);
rc = pthread_cancel(w1);
assert (rc == 0);
```

On to the memory corruption bug: on a 64-bit system (which is what I assume you are using), `sizeof(int) == sizeof(result) == 4`, but `sizeof(void*) == 8`.

This code:

```
 int result =0;
 ...
    pthread_join(w1, (void**)&result)
```

takes an address of 4-byte `result`, and asks `pthread_join` to store an 8-byte value in there. Predictable outcome from this is stack corruption.

I don't see how exactly that triggers the `SIGSEGV`, but once you have undefined behavior in your program, all bets are off.

To fix this, change `result` type to `intptr_t`. I expect the crash to disappear after that fix.

You should also try to use Address Sanitizer: `gcc -fsanitize=address -g ...` before making any changes. There is a high chance it will tell you about stack overflow.

Comment: "Takes an address of 4-byte result, and asks pthread_join to store an 8-byte value in there." Whats wrong with that though? I mean im not trying to store 8 byte result to 4 byte value after all but other way around. Intuition tells that that should fit. Thank you for your tips though, I don't know what fixed it but its working now.

Comment: "What's wrong with that?" -- it's undefined behavior (*anything could happen*). "I mean im not trying to store 8 byte result to 4 byte value" -- yes, you *are*.